# PyQT Intellisense/signatures in Pycharm?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pycharm

I'm just getting started using PyQT 5, and I'm finding the documentation a bit lacking. I took a peek around the directory in site-packages, and couldn't find what I was looking for. What is the best way to:

a) Get Intellisense/Autocomplete working in PyCharm for PyQT5

or b) take a peek at the python implementation of pyQT to see what methods/etc are available to me?

Their docs all just point to QT5 C++ docs, which is great, but I was looking for exact method signatures in python.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like pyQT pretty much follows the exact method signatures, that are available on the QT docs, so this may not really be that necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read [this page](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5131?query=%22) and followed Anže Starič's opinion.

My computer is

- Windows 10
- Python 3.5
- PyQt5
- PyCharm 5.0.1

So I typed:

```
python "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.1\helpers\generator3.py" -x -d "C:\Users\user\.PyCharm50\system\python_stubs\324234324" PyQt5
python "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.1\helpers\generator3.py" -x -d "C:\Users\user\.PyCharm50\system\python_stubs\324234324" PyQt5.QtCore
python "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.1\helpers\generator3.py" -x -d "C:\Users\user\.PyCharm50\system\python_stubs\324234324" PyQt5.QtWidgets
......
```

I tried EVERY module. Of course, you can write a batch file/shell script and you should change those paths to your own.

Finally the autocomplete works.